# How to prove that the following function is unbounded?

Tags: partial-derivative, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f(x,y)$ is provided as follows:

$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$

What i think in this problem is that since $0<\frac {x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq1$ and consequently the given function is $0<\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2}\leq |y|$. Hence, the function should be bounded. Is my reasoning incorrect? But the answer is that the function is unbounded, what am I doing wrong?.

Comment: Is your upper bound $\lvert y\rvert$ bounded itself? When $y\to\infty$... If your upper bound can blow up to infinity, then you cannot conclude anything from what you did.

Comment: Note that $f(t,t)=t/2$.

Comment: Your bound depends on the input value, which is not allowed.